# flash presentation : How to make it easy like this

Tags: flash, presentation

I'm searching a software that offers the possibility of making such as this presentation : 
http://prezi.com/v7n9pbgpnugw/zk-framework/

Thnx a lot.

Comment: Why don't you use the site itself? http://prezi.com/

Comment: it's not free, I'm searching an off-line solution...

Comment: It is free. At least it tells so on the sign up page in which you can also see that the free plan does allow offline presentations.

Comment: It's allows download for off-line presentations, not working off-line to create the presentation.
And I thank you a lot for your answer :)

Comment: And all the presentations are public, but I don't want to have them for everybody (it's my internship presentation and it must be confidential for 5 years)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well well, Prezi is the winner :)

Comment: Prezi is Hungarian, of course it is :D